# How to lock Android device after unlocking with setShowWhenLocked(true);

Tags: java, android, react-native

I am creating a video calling app and have the following code which is called when the application receives a push notification - it unlocks the screen and presents an 'incoming call' user interface:

```java
public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

  @Override
  protected String getMainComponentName() {
    return "x";
  }

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1) {
      setShowWhenLocked(true);
      setTurnScreenOn(true);
    }
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
  }
}
```

This works fine when a call is incoming - the user can interact with the app using the UI presented. However, the problem is is that if the app is in the foreground and the phone is then locked, when the unlock button is pressed on the side of the phone, the app is displayed, instead of the keyguard / lock screen being displayed. It permanently allows access to the app if it is in the foreground and the phone is locked and the unlock button is pressed.

I want the app to appear when the it receives a push notification and the screen is locked, but I also want the user to be able to lock the device fully and not give the user access to the app after pressing the lock button.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know the best solution to that problem is having multiple types of activities.

In the first activity (calling activity) you set setShowWhenLocked and setTurnScreenOn to true (like you did).
When a call comes in, you start the calling activity which handles the call, because you set the two attributes, the activitiy will be shown to the user even if the device is locked.
Furthermore, while the call activitiy is active, the user will be able to "lock" his device (i.e. press the power button), and when he unlocks he will be presented with the calling activity again (without entering the code).
This is the same behaviour as most default android calling/phone apps have.

The second activity is used for your other logic, that should only be accessible when the user really unlocks his phone. (i.e. enter the code)
So, when the phone call is ended, you start the second activity from the calling activity, e.g. like this:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
 this.startActivity(intent);
```

where `this` is the instance of the calling activity

The just started `SecondActivity` will then automatically be locked behind the lockscreen (i.e. not accessible without unlock) if the phone was locked before.

I just tested this behaviour in a small test project, if you need further assistance, just ask.

Comment: Thank you very much! At last someone has answered!! :) I am a JavaScript developer using React Native and have this Java module up and running is what's referred to in React Native as a `Native.Module`. As such, would you mind sharing the code from the small test project to help me try an implement it as my Java skills are minimal? Much appreciated!

Comment: I uploaded a small Java example project here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1t1hausmnkEOYCi66WT0Obwm-KbSN8tm5/view?usp=sharing  
For this test project, I used a broadcast receiver to listen when the screen of the device is locked, then started a 10 second delay ( to simulate a phone call at some point in time when the phone is locked) and afterwards started the "CallingActivity"
When you press the button on the calling activity, the SecondActivity is started (behind the lock screen)  
Does this help you?

Comment: Thank you - I will implement and report back.

Comment: @Mr.Robot have you had time to take a look? Did you understand the example?

Comment: Hi @Lukas Major, yes I've looked at your project and can see that this works so have marked as the correct answer. I haven't however implemented it yet in my own app but will be doing so shortly - thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

In my VoIP app (baresip), I solved the problem by calling requestDismissKeyguard() function also when power button is pressed to unlock the device. That can be detected by registering a broadcast receiver with IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON).  Then if the device is locked with secured keyguard, requestDismissKeyguard() will ask for a PIN code or password before the user can access the app.